# Adding view all in subcategory for magento theme 1.9.2

Tags: category, topmenu, magento1.9.2.3

I want to add view-all option with the subcategory in main menu  for magento theme 1.9.2.
currently my menu appears like this-
category1
 --subcategory1
   --type1
   --type2
 --subcategory2

I want to menu appears like this-
category1
 --subcategory1
   --type1
   --type2
   --view-all
 --subcategory2

Can someone tell me what i can do to make my menu appears like this?